# ffmpeg - concatening audio files onto separate channels in one file

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, wav

I have a list of mono wav files like this

```
1 speaker1.wav
2 speaker2.wav
3 speaker1.wav
4 speaker2.wav
5 speaker1.wav
6 speaker2.wav
```

I want to concatenate them so that I get a single file where each speaker is on either left or right channel in stereo:

```
left : 1 3 5
right:  2 4 6
```

The audio files should play in sequence one after the other alternating between speakers with silence on the channel that is not playing.

This is what I am using for single channel merging:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i filenames.txt output.wav -y
```

filenames.txt is a list of files like

```
file 'speaker1.wav'
file 'speaker2.wav'
file 'speaker1.wav'
file 'speaker2.wav'
file 'speaker1.wav'
file 'speaker2.wav'
```

I have tried using a join like this

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i 1620655780045.txt -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a]join=inputs=2:channel_layout=stereo[a]" -map "[a]" 1620655780045.wav -y
```

but I get an error `Invalid file index 1 in filtergraph description [0:a][1:a]join=inputs=2:channel_layout=stereo[a].` and I'm having trouble understanding how I should address that

Comment: *"with silence on the channel that is not playing."* Is this silence integral to the input files, or is it something that needs to be added with ffmpeg?

Comment: @llogan no - the tracks themselves have no silence, it needs to be added by ffmpeg so that one track is silent while the other plays. With concat this happens by default because they play in sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use the [anullsrc](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#anullsrc) filter to generate silent/filler/dummy audio, then the [join](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#join) filter to add the silence to the appropriate channel for each input, and finally use the [concat](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat) filter to concatenate everything.

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc=cl=mono -i "1 speaker1.wav" -i "2 speaker2.wav" -i "3 speaker1.wav" -i "4 speaker2.wav" -i "5 speaker1.wav" -i "6 speaker2.wav" -filter_complex
"[0][1]join=inputs=2:channel_layout=stereo:map=1.0-FL|0.0-FR[a1];
 [0][2]join=inputs=2:channel_layout=stereo:map=0.0-FL|1.0-FR[a2];
 [0][3]join=inputs=2:channel_layout=stereo:map=1.0-FL|0.0-FR[a3];
 [0][4]join=inputs=2:channel_layout=stereo:map=0.0-FL|1.0-FR[a4];
 [0][5]join=inputs=2:channel_layout=stereo:map=1.0-FL|0.0-FR[a5];
 [0][6]join=inputs=2:channel_layout=stereo:map=0.0-FL|1.0-FR[a6];
 [a1][a2][a3][a4][a5][a6]concat=n=6:a=1:v=0"
output.wav
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting an error with this `1 speaker1.wav: No such file or directory`. I'm assuming the number is some sort of alias, but I can't find the docs for that style of input. I'm using version 4.4-tessus on macos.

Comment: Just realised that was the list of filenames I gave! ‍♂️ Working now!