Ffmpeg concat mono audio to different channels
I am learning a foreign language. I have 2 mono mp3 files generated from Google translate-shell, one for English and the other for another language. How can I concatenation these two files into one file using ffmpeg so that English audio is output to the left ear and the other language to the right ear? Thank you very much.

I found the answer from this url, https://superuser.com/questions/1648074/ffmpeg-concatening-audio-files-onto-separate-channels-in-one-file
